# I am preparing to integrate Disqus with BlogEngine.NET. Any suggestions?

Tags: asp.net, blogengine.net, disqus

I have an existing site running BlogEngine.NET 1.5 and will be upgrading it to the new 1.6 release. I have been asked to integrate Disqus for comments. I have not found any other questions on Disqus and BlogEngine.NET.

I have found some specific instructions here:

http://www.hamishgraham.net/post/Enabling-Disqus-Comments-in-BlogEngineNET.aspx

It explains how to add Disqus to a specific BE.NET theme. But I have existing blog posts and comments. How will these 2 systems work side-by-side? Is there a way to somehow make Disqus work well with the existing comments?

Links:

http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

http://disqus.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Blogengine.net 1.6.1 release.  Disqus is now integrated into the admin area to make it really easy to set up.

Here is a link to the post detailing the install instructions:
http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/post/BlogEngine-161-Update.aspx

Only the web release version is available for 1.6.1 though. I would suggest downloading the source for version 1.6.1 and compiling yourself if you need to customize your build.  Here is the link: http://blogengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/9f0455258305

Answer (score 2):

Disqus will be integrated with BE.NET in the update pack which will be released in April. You might want to hold on just a little bit and then get it working by simply updating to latest.

You *should* be able to migrate your comments to/from Disqus with their migration tool (http://import.disqus.net/).

Comment: It looks like this import tool is still under development. And where I can export comments from BE.NET? I have 1.6 installed but do not see a way to do it.